# What are the C++ Exception Handling mechanisms equivalent to Java's InputMismatchException and IOException Handling

Tags: java, c++

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
/*: 
NAME: Integrated Solution
Create a C++ or Java program for accepting an integer (n) and generate following point series:
x: n integer points from 0 to (n-1)
y: y=x*x

Design an effective mechanism for plotting these with minimal or nil effort from the user.*/

public class Integrated_Solution
 {
  private static final String FILENAME = "122.py";
  public static void main (String[] args)
   {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n = -1;
    boolean flag = false;
    System.out.println ("Enter value of n: ");
    while(flag==false)
     {
      try
       {
        n = sc.nextInt();               // Inputting range from user
        if (n >= 0)
         flag=true;
        else
         System.out.println("Enter a positive value.");
       }
      catch (InputMismatchException e) // Exception Handling For any mismatch types (float, string etc.)
       {
        System.out.println ("Enter a positive integer value. \n");
        sc.nextLine();
       }
     }
    try
     {
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (FILENAME); // Create a new file with the given filename
      fw.write("from pylab import linspace, plot, stem, show, title, xlabel, ylabel\n"+                     
               "n = " + n + "\n" +
               "x = linspace (0, n - 1, n)\n"+
               "figure (num = None, figsize = (16,8), dpi = 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')\n"
               "title ('Plot for graph $f(x) = x^2$')\n" +
               "xlabel ('$x$')\n" +
               "ylabel ('$x^2$')\n" +
               "plot (x, x * x, 'b')\n"+    
               "stem (x, x * x, linefmt = 'g-', markerfont= 'bo')\n"+                                                       
               "show ()\n");            
      fw.close();
     }
    catch (IOException e)
     {
      System.out.println("Could not write file !!" + e.getMessage());
     }
    try
     {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("python " + FILENAME); // Execute the created python file 
     }
    catch (IOException e)
     {
      System.out.println("Could not execute script. Call to runtime failed. " + e.getMessage ());
     } 
    sc.close(); 
   }
 }
```

This is my Java solution. However I wish to achieve the same exception handling mechanisms in a C++ program as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
 {
  ofstream outputFile;
  outputFile.open("122.py");    
  cout << "Enter the value of n : ";
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  outputFile << "from pylab import linspace, plot, stem, show, title, xlabel, ylabel, figure\n" <<                      
               "n = " << n << "\n" <<
               "x = linspace (0, n - 1, n)\n"<< 
               "figure (num = None, figsize = (16,8), dpi = 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')\n" <<
               "title ('Plot for graph $f(x) = x^2$')\n" <<            
               "xlabel ('$x$')\n" <<
               "ylabel ('$x^2$')\n" <<
               "plot (x, x * x, 'b')\n"<<   
               "stem (x, x * x, linefmt = 'g-', markerfont= 'bo')\n" <<             
               "show ()\n";
  outputFile.close();
  system ("python 122.py");
 }
```

The above is my C++ program minus the exception handling. What changes should I make to achieve the same sense of security as my Java program ?

Also any advice on improving my Java or C++ code (even if it is not related to exception handling as per question) would be greatly appreciated as well.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: While you call a Python script, the Python part is really irrelevant to the question itself, and so you should not have the `python` tag.

Comment: As for equivalents, there are none. Java and C++ are two very different languages that does things like exceptions very differently. In C++, for example, a thrown exception is very expensive. This is why it's rarely used for things like validation or simple error handling.

Comment: If you want to learn how to handle errors from the `system` function, I recommend e.g. [this `std::system` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system). Or the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) or [the POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) for platform-specific information.

Comment: Some suggestions - as you wish. In your java code you're closing the resources in the `try` statement which is bad, because they are not closed in case your code throws an exception. You should add a finally statement after the catch method or as a good practice - if something implements the `AutoCloseable` or `Closeable` interfaces it can be used in the try with resources statement which closes the resources, even after an exception has been thrown and even if it was uncaught, more info here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easy set when which exceptions will be thrown. The most common case is when the `std::istream::failbit` or `istream::badbit` (to be honest `std::ios::badbit` and `std::ios::failbit`, they are inherited):

```
int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin.exceptions(std::istream::failbit | std::istream::badbit);
  try {
    std::cin >> n;
  } catch(istream::failure) {
    std::cout << "failed to read value" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The same thing applies to `std::ifstream` because it also inherits after `std::istream`.

To check for failure in the `system()` function I'd recommend following the MSDN for Windows and POSIX for Linux, Mac and other Unix based/inspired systems. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx), [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) - as you can see here, the behavior is different depending on the system you're using.